# add multiple object to ArrayList using for looping java

Tags: java, arraylist

I try to add multiple object in ArrayList, this is my code

```
ArrayList<WordData> unique = new ArrayList<WordData>();
WordData tempWordData = new WordData(); 

        for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
        {
            String temp_word = word.get(i);
            tempWordData.addWord(temp_word);
            unique.add(tempWordData);               
        }
```

but, all the data in `unique` `ArrayList` was `word.get(2)`, not `word.get(0), word.get(1), word.get(2)`

Please help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add an element to the ArrayList, you add a reference to that element, if you change the element, that change will be reflected in the ArrayList.

You have to create a new WordData inside the loop:

```
ArrayList<WordData> unique = new ArrayList<WordData>();

for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
    WordData tempWordData = new WordData(); 
    String temp_word = word.get(i);
    tempWordData.addWord(temp_word);
    unique.add(tempWordData);               
}
```

Comment: Got my +1 for the extra explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing your `WordData` instance inside the loop:

```
ArrayList<WordData> unique = new ArrayList<WordData>();

for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
    String temp_word = word.get(i);
    WordData tempWordData = new WordData();
    tempWordData.addWord(temp_word);
    unique.add(tempWordData);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a WordData object in every iteration:

```
ArrayList<WordData> unique = new ArrayList<WordData>();

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        WordData tempWordData = new WordData(); 
        String temp_word = word.get(i);
        tempWordData.addWord(temp_word);
        unique.add(tempWordData);               
    }
```